# Difference between updating an app from Android Studio and from Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I've made a major update to an app, and it installs fine when I first install the old app and then the new version on my phone. The SharedPreferences are intact.

However, when I install the app from Play Store and then update to the new version through beta, the installation works but the SharedPreferences seem to be corrupt, because I get a crash when the app tries to read them.

Is there a difference between the two methods? Why do I get different results when the hardware and code are the same?

Comment: your code and hardware are same but your app signature is different. Due to this your old app is uninstalled before new one is installed. During uninstallation shared pref get deleted.

Comment: @IllegalArgument I don't think this is the problem. From developer.android.com: " The system allows the update if the certificates match. If you sign the new version with a different certificate, you must assign a different package name to the application—in this case, the user installs the new version as a completely new application."

Comment: I was assuming you had one app having a debug certificate and another release certificate. If you run your app directly from ecllipse without exporting then what I said above will occur when a new app is downloaded from play store

Comment: @IllegalArgument In the working test both the old and the new versions have debug certificates. In the not working test (the one on Play) the old and the new have the same release certificate.

Comment: If your phone is rooted(if not - it takes <10 minutes), you can manually read SharedPreferences and check if they actually get corrupted, or different SharedPreferences are used.

Comment: @Rickard You can't publish to the app store with a debug cert afaik.